# Spring boot The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

We have 100% working project.

It works perfectly on 2 Windows computers, but when I clone it from repo to Mac - OS El Capitan, Eclipse with STS plugin - I can not built it, I get this error:

```
Archive for required library: '/Users/{username}/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar' in project '{project name}' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file {project name}
```

In Maven pom.xml I have added required dependency, but it still doesn't solve the problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.47</version>
</dependency>
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete `/Users/{username}/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar`, and download "bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar" (and verify that it downloaded correctly) then place it there manually.

Comment: Ok, I tried what you said! So in /Users/{username}/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/ folder I have 5 files, they are: _maven.repositories, bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar.lastUpdated, bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.pom and bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.pom.sha1. So I deleted the bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar file, downloaded it from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47 and copied it back to same folder. But it did not solve the problem!

Comment: Why my project takes jar files from /Users/{username}/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/ folder? It is not project folder!

Comment: That's your local repository. See the [settings reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-settings/settings.html) for more. Also, make sure you right click and "Maven > Update Project" (or ALT-F5) when you add a dependency.

Comment: Yes I did Update Project

Comment: Well **cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file** is *explicitly* telling you what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, I solved building problem by deleting the whole /Users/{username}/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/  folder. Then after Maven/UpdateProject it recreated this folder and now project builds! Thank you!